# pass event to a rendered component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a rendered component that will do something when I click on it:

```
// A normal Vue component using a render function
Vue.component('greeting', {
    methods: {
        sayHello(){
            alert('hello')
        }
        
    },
    render(createElement){
        var self = this
        return createElement(
            'button', 
            {
                '@click': self.sayHello
            },
            'if you click here I will say hello')
    }
})


new Vue({ 
    el: '#app'
})
```

I'm expecting an alert when I click on the button.  As far as I can tell, this will render something like

```
<button @click="sayHello" />
```

where the method sayHello is defined in the Vue instance.

Why doesn't this work?

https://codepen.io/dvdgdnjsph/pen/NWNwYOQ

Comment: Why don't you directly use ```template``` to create button ?

Comment: @Vipulw  I have something more complex that I'm working on that requires passing events to rendered functions.  This is supposed to be a minimal example, not something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working copy of your example in this fiddle. I have modified the way we write click event. Refer below code snippet.

[Working Button Click via Render Function](https://jsfiddle.net/jxwfm396/)

```js
Vue.component('DraggableList', {
  methods: {
    sayHello() {
      alert('hello')
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    var self = this;
    return createElement(
      'button', // tag name
      {
        on: {
          click: this.sayHello
        }
      }, 'if you click here I will say hello'
    )
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    padding: 2em;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid input{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.polite{
    font-family: cursive;
    color: gray;
}
.rude{
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="grid">
    <draggable-list></draggable-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and what you did.

Comment: @Dharman I discussed approaches with the person in comments of questions and then only gave the solution. Also, by including the code snippet it was pretty clear to understand. Will remember for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the passed events need to be specified as 'on', like so:

```
{ 
  on: {
   click: somefunction
  }

}
```

https://codepen.io/dvdgdnjsph/pen/NWNwYOQ

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#_3-x-syntax-2